# Test class for Continuation Chaining

Tags: apex, continuation

Has anyone ever done a test class for continuation chaining (Multiple Asynchronous Callouts)?

Comment: You won't be able to test multiple async jobs, just the first one.  By breaking up testing you should be able to have confidence in your testing, asserts need to go after `Test.stopTest()`

Comment: This sort of [Testing a Database.Batchable implementation](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/testing-a-database-batchable-implementation/) can test multiple batch logic and batch chaining as it runs synchronously to work around the lack of test support for multiple async calls. Obviously you need to use small batch sizes to stay within governor limits.